# How to add entry to right click menu?

Tags: centos, gnome

I have CentOS 6 and i need Terminal a lot. i want to add an entry "Open Terminal to the menu when i right click on a blank space in my desktop. How can I do this?

Comment: Why to *ever* have *a* desktop? I explain, if that were a KDE system, you could configure a plasma widget to be there occupying all the desktop with a terminal. Maybe a better question for you is *How to configure a Terminal startup at GNOME boot?*. Look for 'quake linux tilda yakuake' in Bing, and profit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install this package:

```
$ sudo yum install nautilus-open-terminal
```

[image: ss of right click]

#### References

- [GNOME Sources](http://download.gnome.org/sources/nautilus-open-terminal/)
- [Nautilus “Open in Terminal” on Fedora/CentOS/Red Hat (RHEL)](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nautilus-open-in-terminal-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

Comment: is it possible to change the place of the "open in terminal" to the first row?

Comment: @HojatTaheri - yes it is. I can't answer specifically now, I need to step out of the house for a bit, I can answer when I get back or you can google for specifics.